# When using the comparative tag, should we include the two mythologies we are comparing?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed some questions that only have the comparative tag without any mythologies -

- [Odin's Counterpart](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/odins-counterpart)
- [Are there any other mythologicals that got a replacement metal arm, other than Nuada, Lugh Llaw Ereint, and Sigurd?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/are-there-any-other-mythologicals-that-got-a-replacement-metal-arm-other-than-n)
- [Did ancient myths center on deities because individualism was not valued?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/did-ancient-myths-center-on-deities-because-individualism-was-not-valued)

But the majority link the mythologies- so that's what I use.

So do we tag in the individual mythologies, as long as it is not [all-encompassing](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/does-every-culture-have-a-sort-of-deluge-myth)?

Answer (score 3):

I think it would not only make perfect sense, but should kinda be required! You can't compare two things if you don't state the two things you're comparing.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the three, not the individualism one, are "comparing" questions. The OPs didn't specifically name, or "link", the mythologies in their question. They did provide characters from different mythologies, and looked to find more, or to find how they do/don't compare. For those two the tag seems proper, and server as examples that can be tagged `comparative` without needing the tags or names of the mythologies in question, especially as the mythology to compare may not be known until the answer is written. For cases where the tags can be applied, edit by experienced members to help those with less experience can be a good idea.